# Windows application drops all WCF and TCP connections

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, tcp

I have a windows service that is primarily a WCF host (net.tcp binding) for a few hundred clients. It hosts a number of different WCF services some of which are duplex.

It also has a plain TCP connection to one particular client.

To complicate matters further, the applicaton loads a third party SDK that makes futher TCP connections to other servers.

As the clients have scaled up I now find it randomly drop all network connections: more specifically all the WCF channels stop responding AND the plain TCP connection stops responding. The WCF channels are not disconnected, rather they stay connected until they eventually timeout (after one minute).

The clients are eventually able to remake their connections and the TCP connection is also recovered.

I suspect the application may just become too busy to service all connections and the TCP buffers may be full. But if this was the case I would think it would respond more slowly - however this is not the case, all the connections stop at the same time and do not recover (the application would easily be able to process all pending requests within the 1 minute timeout).

I don't expect anyone to solve this issue directly as it is rather vague and I am unable to provide sample code but I hope I might find some tips of how to debug the issue.

Comment: Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and that should help much better than SO. WCF tracing might reveal some data but personally I believe some hang dumps and some analysis can show the culprit easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting. I will try and get a dump from it the next time it stops working, provided I can catch it in time. WCF tracing has not revealed anything. It seems to be at the TCP level.